# How can I use an URL (being a field content) as a contextual filter in views?

Tags: views

I'm working on an academic wiki containing two types of pages: **an 'Author page' and an 'Article page'**. I am trying to create a **block view displaying all the articles written by an author into her corresponding page**. The view selects the 'Article pages' using a content type filter and I tried to use contextual filters to select the articles written by a particular author.

The difficult part is that the 'Author page' and the 'Article page' do not share a similar field for the author's name. However, **when creating an 'Article page', the user has to enter all participating authors and the URLs corresponding to their respective page** in the wiki.

So what I would like to do is to **use the last component of this URL (the node ID of the 'Author page') and compare it to the node ID of the page the user is looking at**. If the IDs match, the view displays selected fields from the 'Article pages' which have written by the author the user is looking at. But so far I have been unsuccessful in doing so, any hint on how I could perform this functionality?

I'm new using Drupal (and site building actually), so I apologize if my question lacks clarity or details.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Igor

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler solution than what I was trying to do: I used node references. That's exactly what I needed but I wasn't aware of the existence of this functionality. So yes, the solution is simply to use a node reference to link the 'Article page' to the 'Author page'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while ago. I understand that you have already solved the issue for yourself but I think a reply may help other who stumble here through Google.

To set the contextual filter you need to add the Relationship, "Content: Author" (this is located under the advanced tab when creating the view).

The add a Contextual filter "User: Uid". When making the filter you also need to set the following option:

Under **When the default value is not available**

Provide deault value of type "User ID from URL".

Comment: Thanks a lot Sigvard for the input. In my understanding, the solution you suggest would be very helpful if the "Author" I was referring to was an actual user of the website. However, when I refer to an Author, it should be considered as a simple page. The website I am building is a participatory repository of academic works and their respective authors. So again, the author is not a user. I realize the terminology might be confusing, I should have stressed the difference in my question. Thanks a lot for your answer though, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Darn, I thought I finally could help someone in the community.

But I will probably end up using your solution for a completely different issue. =)